# How to use vuesax $vs.notify outside of vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuesax

I am using `$vs.notify` to show message that comes from db. So thought of using it in the actions.js. but getting error as `TypeError: Cannot read property 'notify' of undefined`. Is there any way that i could use it in action.js file.
used code is here:

```
addTag({
    commit
}, tag) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Vue.prototype.$http.post('/tags/add/', {
                tag
            })
            .then((response) => {
                commit('ADD_TAG', Object.assign(response.data.data[0]))
                Vue.prototype.$vs.notify({
                    title: 'Success',
                    text: `tag-${response.data.data[0].name} added suceesfully`,
                    iconPack: 'feather',
                    icon: 'icon-alert-circle',
                    color: 'success'
                })
                resolve(response)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                reject(error)
            })
    })
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AslHv.png)

Comment: `$vs.notify` alone does not work?

Answer (score 2):

[`Vuesax`](https://lusaxweb.github.io/vuesax/) doesn't register anything on `Vue.prototype`, which is why you get that particular error message.  It seems the service is added to each component instead.  It's also not available for importing in the module.  So, as a workaround, you can add it to the prototype yourself.

Add the service in *`App.vue`* to `Vue.prototype`:

***App.vue***

```js
<script>
import Vue from 'vue';

export default {
  created() {
    Vue.prototype.$vs = this.$vs;
  }
}
</script>
```

Now you can use it the way you tried in your post:

***actions.js***

```js
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.prototype.$vs.notify(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [official documentation](https://lusaxweb.github.io/vuesax/components/notifications.html#notifications-defaults), it states that

> To add a notification we have the global function $vs.notify

So, try using `this._vm.$vs.notify` or maybe `this._vm.notify` in your vuex action.